# Изменение параметров объекта в массиве

Tags: java

Класс `SchoolBoard` хранит в себе массив данных с объектами:

```
public class SchoolBoard  {

public List<School> scli = new ArrayList<>();

public SchoolBoard()
{

    scli.add(new School(0,20,0,"Ugly"));
    scli.add(new School(30,20,50,"Normal"));
    scli.add(new School(50, 50, 100, "Best"));
}

}
```

Класс `School`:

```
public class School {

private int education = 0;
private int space = 20;
private int cost = 0;
private String name = " ";

//-----CONSTRUCTOR------

public School(int education, int space, int cost, String name)
{
   this.cost = cost;
   this.space = space;
   this.education = education;
   this.name = name;
}


//----SETTERS-----------


public void setEducation(int education) {
    this.education = education;
}

public void setSpace(int space) {
    this.space = space;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

//-----GETTERS----------


public int getEducation() {
    return education;
}

public int getSpace() {
    return space;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

И есть класс с детьми, который из массива перебирает параметры объекта, затем найдя, изменяет другой параметр (дети ищут школу с лучшим образованием, а затем кол-во детей (`children = 7`) заполняет места в школе (`space`)

```
     SchoolBoard sclb = new SchoolBoard();


    private int children = 7;
    public School maxSchool = null;



    public void chooseSchool()
    {

    for (School school : sclb.scli) {
        if (maxSchool == null) {
            maxSchool = school;
        } else if (maxSchool.getEducation() < school.getEducation()) {
            maxSchool = school;
        }
    }
    if (maxSchool != null) {
        maxSchool.setSpace(maxSchool.getSpace() - children);
    }

    }
```

Я написал интерфейс проверять значения, и понял, что у меня изменяется только значение объекта `maxSchool()`, а параметры объектов в массиве остаются неизменны.

Comment: А как вы проверяете изменились ли данные? Выглядит-то всё, вроде, нормально...

Comment: Судя по коду, должно измениться содержимое только одного из элементов массива, того элемента на который ссылается maxSchool

Comment: @ЮрийСПб создал frame, на него залипил label и  buttons 
с помощью кнопок вызываю нужные методы, а на лейблах ставлю нужные значения и смотрю. Ну вот методично 0,1,2 ячейки массива
(test1.setText("EducationCap " + sclb.scli.get(0).getSpace());) 
попробовал, ничего не меняется :(((
я вообще не знаю, что и куда теперь тыкать, я уверен, что должно работать, но увы :(

Comment: @Valentin да, выборка объекта происходит правильно, и объект, на который ссылается maxSchool, должен менять значение space на кол-во children

Comment: Я всё догоняю, в чем логика, но хоть убейте, понять не могу, почему не работает

Comment: Пройдитесь после изменения объекта циклом по их списку и выведите в консоль интересующие вас значения полей. Должно показать, что один из объектов значения свои изменил. Судя по всему ваш вопрос не про изменение свойств, а про их отображение. Т.е. обновление виджетов.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c629323/v629323957/3daf7/4yiZFYC4_Sk.jpg

ну вот, значение max.School.getSpace() меняется как надо, минус семь

а в консоле выводятся три параметра space из массива

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы проверяете один и тот же список? Может у вас два экземпляра SchoolBoard?

Comment: Покажите _весь_ код (а лучше, сделайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Vartlok Боже мооой)) 
вот в чем прикол... :))) так и есть, я создал несколько объектов класса и работаю с разными)) 
БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО)))

Comment: Как закрыть вопрос и поставить @Vartlok большой плюс?)

Comment: @OgneFF да никак =) Удали вопрос, чтобы он не шел в статистику как не отвеченный, всё-таки ответ будет очень мало полезным.

Comment: Не-не-не! Вопрос удалять не надо! @Vartlok, опубликуйте, пж-та, в ответе, что надо следить за тем, чтобы проводить операции с один объектом и не путаться в ссылках на разные. Тогда ТС сможет его принять. Считаю, что вопрос и ответ имеют право на жизнь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как было выяснено в комментариях, проблема была в нескольких экземплярах класса `SchoolBoard` и соответственно на UI выходились значения из одного, а в консоль выводились из другого.

Вообще, что-бы изначально избежать такой ситуации можно использовать шаблон проектирования [Одиночка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))([Singltone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)). НО! Не надо увлекаться с этим шаблоном и применять его только в том случае, когда это реально необходимо.

Так хотелось бы обратить внимание на такой шаблон как [Блокировка с двойной проверкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking)([Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)), который необходимо применять в  многопоточной среде.

Comment: Ништяк, я программировал без этих знаний)
поэтому часто путался

Comment: спасибо еше раз)

Comment: @OgneFF рад помочь =)